# How to select drop-down value using selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, html, css

My Code:

```
WebElement objSearchBy = wait.until(
    ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
        By.xpath("//html/body/div[I]/div[2]/form/div[2]/label[I]")
    )
);
```

HTML Code:

[image: HTML code for drop-down title name]

Getting below Output:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for presence of element located by: By.xpath: //html/body/div[I]/div[2]/form/div[2]/label[I] (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)

Comment: Please don't insert snap of your html code. It will be hard for other developers to recreate the issue, because no one is going to write that code. Instead use SO snippet.

Comment: In general, the easier you make it for someone else to test your code, the faster and more likely you are to get an answer to your question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Expand SELECT tag and see the available options under it.Based on required option update second line of this code.

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("loc_code")));
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("your option text");
```

or

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("loc_code")));
dropdown.selectByValue("option2");
```

or

```
dropdown.selectByIndex(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls check xpath correctness: if it was autogenerated, are values `div[I]` and `label[I]` correct?

Try to use meaningful paths, or precise identifiers, for ex `#loc_code` here